# Count the unique elements in the array of struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I am facing a problem in a realization of structs with cars, I need to output the count of each car in garage, so in my case the output should be:
Audi 3
Ford 1
Porsche 1
I am stack with the count of the unique elements, I know that it is necessary to make the array of strings and to go through my struct and to add new element each time when u reach the end and the element was not found in the array of strings.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <Windows.h>
     #include <time.h>

    typedef struct Auto{
        char Model  [16];
        char Number [8];
        char Color  [10];
        char Name   [16];
    }; 

    int main() {

    int i, j, counter = 0;
    char EnteredModel[16] = { "Audi" };
    struct Auto MyAuto[5] = { { "Audi",   "x007x", "blue",  "Alexander" },
                              { "Ford",   "x777x", "red",   "Andrey" },
                              { "Porsche","a000b", "white", "Oleg"},
                              { "Audi",   "x007x", "blue",  "Sergey"},
                              { "Audi",   "f666f", "black", "Daniel"} };

    //printf("Enter the number of the interested model: ");
    //scanf("%s", &EnteredModel);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("#####################################################\n");
            printf("#Model           #Number  #Color     #Name          #\n");
            printf("#####################################################\n");
        }
        if (strcmp(MyAuto[i].Model, EnteredModel)) {
            printf("%-17s%-9s%-11s%-17s\n", MyAuto[i].Model, MyAuto[i].Number, MyAuto[i].Color, MyAuto[i].Name);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (strcmp(MyAuto[i].Model, MyAuto[j].Model) == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("%s = %d\n", MyAuto[j].Model, counter);
        counter = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but the `typedef` can be removed, it has no purpose here.

Comment: `if (strcmp(MyAuto[i].Model, EnteredModel)==0) {`: you forgot the test against zero you get the opposite. but your question is still very unclear.

Comment: To me it is unclear what your asking. What problems do you have with the posted code?

Comment: The simplest way I can think about would be be an array of pointers to `Auto` structure. The number of elements in the array would be equal to the number of cars could be in the garage. It should be initialized to all null pointers, and any pointer that isn't a null pointer means that there is a car at the specific position.

Comment: i need to print the amount of the unique models of cars in the array of struct

Comment: To count the number of each model, you will need a list of the models and the number found.  If you know about dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al), you can create the list as you go.  If not, create a 'model counter' structure with room for the model name and a count; keep a record of how many models you've seen. When you process a new entry from your main array, find the name in the model counter list; if already there, add one to the count; if not there, add it with a count of 1.

Comment: unrelated: why do you have number as a string? if you want to count the cars have an integer there instead initialized to 0 and then increment that every time you find the car you are looking for. or is that some other number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make a "model counted" array with the same length as your current array and use it to "remember" which cars you have already counted.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Auto{
  char Model  [16];
  char Number [8];
  char Color  [10];
  char Name   [16];
};

int main() {

  int i, j, counter=0;
  char EnteredModel[16] = { "Audi" };
  struct Auto MyAuto[5] = { { "Audi",   "x007x", "blue",  "Alexander" },
                            { "Ford",   "x777x", "red",   "Andrey" },
                            { "Porsche","a000b", "white", "Oleg"},
                            { "Audi",   "x007x", "blue",  "Sergey"},
                            { "Audi",   "f666f", "black", "Daniel"} };
  int modelCounted[5] = {0};

  //printf("Enter the number of the interested model: ");
  //scanf("%s", &EnteredModel);

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      printf("#####################################################\n");
      printf("#Model           #Number  #Color     #Name          #\n");
      printf("#####################################################\n");
    }
    if (strcmp(MyAuto[i].Model, EnteredModel) == 0) {
                            // NOTICE:        ^^^^
      printf("%-17s%-9s%-11s%-17s\n", MyAuto[i].Model, MyAuto[i].Number, MyAuto[i].Color, MyAuto[i].Name);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (!modelCounted[j])  // Only enter inner-loop if car hasn't been counted already
    {
      for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strcmp(MyAuto[i].Model, MyAuto[j].Model) == 0) {
          counter++;
          modelCounted[i] = 1;  // Mark car as counted
        }
      }
      printf("%s = %d\n", MyAuto[j].Model, counter);
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
#####################################################
#Model           #Number  #Color     #Name          #
#####################################################
Audi             x007x    blue       Alexander
Audi             x007x    blue       Sergey
Audi             f666f    black      Daniel

Audi = 3
Ford = 1
Porsche = 1
```

BTW: Notice the change to the first `strcmp`